# How to represent facial features from video and classify high/low personality traits from facial features?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, feature-selection, feature-extraction

The dataset has 3-minute 30fps video conversations (no audio) of 150 extroverted and 150 introverted individuals. The goal is to classify them as "introverts" or "extroverts" based on their facial features.

I have extracted 35-dim facial action unit features using open-face for each frame. Then took an average of features from 5400 frames (for each video) for each sample and used an SVM classifier, resulting in 70% ACC.

- What are other statistical measures to represent the entire data, instead of the average feature?
- What are some other deep learning-based approaches for extracting/representing entire time series of facial features from videos and classifying binary personality types ("introvert" or "extrovert")?

Answer (score 0):

You can use open-face to yield a 35-dim feature vector for each frame, as you said, and then treat each video as a *sequence* of features of shape `(num_frames, 35)` such that the entire dataset is of shape `(300, num_frames, 35)`.

Then you can train a recurrent neural network classifier, like a LSTM that takes in a sequence of `num_frames` 35-dim vectors and yields a single number: the binary class.

Alternatively, I think you can replace the feature extraction by open-face with an end-to-end model by using 3D convolutional layers, and then an LSTM, with a final dense layer.

Comment: Tried that approach but got poor results. 

3min@30fps = 5400 frames and LSTMs cannot handle capturing important features from longer sequences. There are most frames common between the 2 classes where the facial expression is neutral.

Comment: @TheBiometricsGuy I see, what about using a transformer instead? Otherwise, you could try a sort of "hierarchical" approach in which you train a LSTM on `T `frames so having a total of 5400/T LSTMs, which, in turn, are aggregated by another LSTM or Dense layer: it's an idea, I don't know if it may work at all.